# Grails Pagination in a search query page

Tags: grails

I am using following query to filter results  in grails.

```
userList = SecUser.all.findAll{it.merchants.findAll {it.name.toLowerCase()=~ searchString.toLowerCase()}.size()>0}
```

In this code i have Users and each User have multiple merchants. I extract only that user whose merchant name matches a certain pattern.

Now i further have to filter these users on:

```
params.max
params.offset
```

So that i can perform pagination on them. Kindly please help me with this problem.

Comment: It will be easy and clear if you just use HQL. Add both the domain class in order to get an appropriate HQL query. :)

Answer (score 0):

This has not been tested, but try something like this:

```
def query = SecUser.where {
    merchants.any { merchant ->
        merchant.name.equalsIgnoreCase( searchString )
    }
}
def userList = query.findAll(max: params.max, offset: params.offset)
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving me ArrayOutOfBoundExpextion on first line

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood Can you post the stacktrace, please?